# Convergence of a trigonometric sequence $x_n=\frac{\sin(\frac{n\pi}{4})}{n}+\frac{n}{2n^2 + \cos n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The sequence given is $$x_n=\frac{\sin(\frac{n\pi}{4})}{n}+\frac{n}{2n^2 + \cos n}$$

The limit $a$ of this sequence is just the sum of the limits $$a=\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=0+0=0$$

So the sequence converges to zero, and to prove this we have to find some index number $N<n$ such that the distance from $x_n$ to the limit $a$ is always less than any positive $\epsilon$. My idea would be to solve the inequality $$-\epsilon<x_n<\epsilon$$

for $n$, but I think I'm making things way too complicated here. Any hints would be appreciated. Edit : Also, this proof has to be done according to the definition of converging sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|x_n| \leq \frac  1n+\frac n {2n^{2}-1} \leq \frac  1n+\frac  1n$ for all $n \geq 1$ So $|x_n| <\epsilon$ whenever $n >\frac  2 {\epsilon}$.

Comment: so $\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n}$ is the maximum value of the sequence. Since $\epsilon$ must be greater than that value also, we can solve $N$ from that equation just as well?

Comment: Yes, you can take any $N >2/\epsilon$.

Comment: shouldnt it be any $N<2/\epsilon$

Comment: @juhani No. If $n >N$ where $N >\frac 2  {\epsilon}$ then $\frac 2 n <\epsilon}$.